# Как получить часть url по условию?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите, как составить регулярное выражение под условие:
Есть url вида: `http://example.com/news/news-name`

Нужно отсечь `http://example.com`, и оставить `/news/news-name`, при этом news-name будет меняться, в зависимости от названия новость.

P.S.#1 ещё небольшая хотелка, хоть и не обязательна. Можно ли не "хардкодить" название сайта, а в шаблон подставить что-то вроде
`baseUrl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;`

Такое возможно?

P.S.#2 юзать `new URL` нельзя, нужна поддержка IE

Comment: `location.pathname`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Накидал такую

```js
var pathnameNews =  'http://example.com/news/news-name'
pathnameNews.match('/news/.*')[0]
```